# Showing that $\{x\mid f(x)\leq g(x)\}$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology

Problem statement:

> Let $Y$ be an ordered set in the order topology and $X$ a topological
>   space. $f,g:\, X\to Y$ are continuous.  Show that $\{x\mid f(x)\leq g(x)\}$ is closed.

**My thoughts:**

In case $Y=\mathbb{R}$ I would define $h=g-f$ and say that the above
set is $h^{-1}([0,\infty))$ which is closed by continuity of $h$.
But in an ordered set $Y$ there is no meaning of $g-f$.

Can someone give me a hint ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165432/let-y-be-an-ordered-set-in-the-order-topology-with-f-gx-rightarrow-y-contin?rq=1

Comment: I got confused reading this for the first time, you might want to consider putting the problem statement in the question as well as in the title, instead of just the hypothesis in the question and the problem statement in the title.