# Closed subsets under order topology and continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, analysis

This question below was asked  in a phd qualifying exam and I was unable to solve it. So, I am asking here.

> Let (Y, $\leq$ )  be a linearly ordered set and let U denote the order topology on Y. Furthermore, let (X,T) be a topological space and let f, g:X->Y be continuous functions.

(a)Prove that { x$\epsilon$ X: f(x)$\leq$ g(x) } is a closed subset of X.

( b) Define a functionh:X->Y by h(x)= min{ f(x) , g(x) } for all x$\epsilon$ X. Prove that h is continuous.

> My attempt -> I tried by assuming f(x) > g(x) but I couldn't find a contradiction.

Also, I am unable to solve (b) as I am a not much familiar with the Order topology. ( It was very terribly taught to us by a stupid instructor).

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $Y$ be an ordered set in the order topology with $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ continuous, show that $\{x:f(x)\leq g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165432/let-y-be-an-ordered-set-in-the-order-topology-with-f-gx-rightarrow-y-contin)

Comment: @Proxava no, my question has 2 parts!!

Comment: If you scroll down to the first answer all of your question is answered (including the comments to that answer).

Comment: @Proxava Ok,I got it thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $C = \{(y,y') \in Y \times Y: y \le y'\}$ is closed in $Y \times Y$.

Proof: Suppose that $(y,y') \notin C$, so that $y > y'$. There are two cases to consider:

- If there is some $z \in Y$ such that $y > z > y'$ then $z^\uparrow=\{z' \in Y: z' > z\}$ is open in the order topology on $Y$ by *definition* of the order topology. The set $z^\downarrow = \{z' \in Y: z' < z\}$ is open in the order topology as well. So $z^\uparrow \times z^\downarrow$ is open in $Y \times Y$ (of the form open times open) and contains $(y,y')$ by definition, and if $(u,u') \in z^\uparrow \times z^\downarrow$ we know that $u > z$ and $u' < z$ and so $u' < u$, or $(u,u') \in C^\complement$. We could also say that $(z^\uparrow \times z^\downarrow) \cap C= \emptyset$. However we formulate it, it either shows that $(y,y')$ is an interior point of $C^\complement$ or not a point of the closure of $C$, as required.
- If there is no such $z$ (so no points strictly inbetween $y$ and $y'$ in the order) we use the product open $(y')^\uparrow \times y^\downarrow \ni (y,y')$ instead. If the set would intersect $C$, say in $(u,u')$ we'd have $u \le u'$ from $(u,u') \in C$ and $u > y', u' < y$ from the open set definition, and then $y' < u \le u' < y$ but then $u$ would have been such a non-existent inbetween point.

Now, if $f,g: X \to Y$ are continuous, so is $f \nabla g: X \to Y \times Y$ defined by $(f \nabla g)(x): (f(x), g(x))$ because $\pi_1 \circ (f \nabla g) = f$ and $\pi_2 \circ (f \nabla g)= g$ and the universal property for continuity into products.

Now, $$\{x\mid f(x) \le g(x)\} = \{x\mid (f(x), g(x)) \in C\}= \{x: (f \nabla g)(x) \in C\} = (f \nabla g)^{-1}[C]$$ is the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous map and hence closed.

Almost the same proof shows that $C'=\{x \mid g(x) \le f(x)\}$ is closed too (interchange $f$ and $g$'s roles).

Note that (b) follows as

$$\min(f,g)= \begin{cases}
f(x) & x \in C \\
g(x) & x \in C'
\end{cases}$$

and we apply the [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma) to the two closed sets $C \cup C'=X$.

Comment: Can you also answer this question asked by me if you got some spare time. I don't know why but people are not answering it , although i have given context . I shall be really thankful to you!!https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816199/defining-a-new-metric-d-wrt-to-a-metric-d-such-that-d-is-bounded-and-d-and-d